# Rails 3.2, Refinery Edge Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, passenger, comments, refinerycms

I am trying to deploy my Refinery blog CMS to a staging server.

The app works fine on my development but annoyingly it does not online. I get the following error from passenger:

No such file to load -- /path/to/app/releases/20120217232643/webapp/app/mailers/refinery/blog/comment_mailer

I am totally baffled, being new to Rails, I though it would work out the box. Especially as it works somewhat fine on my development machine.

I would appreciate a pointer or two.

Thanks

M.

Comment: How are you deploying to your web server?  Could there be any significant differences?

Comment: I am using  Capistrano, however, running rake commands are problematic and result in errors so until I figure that out I'm having to ssh in and manually run them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it with Rails 3.0 you can install it with `gem install rails -v 3.0`.  According to the "Getting Started Guide" (see http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-refinery) Refinery runs on Rails 3.0.

Comment: Cool I think that may be the best way for now till 3.2 and refinery are stable. It is just odd that it works locally in dev but online its fails. ... Soon as I try later today I will get back with the results on whether it worked or not

Comment: I think your comment helped in that one needs to read care fully the getting stated guide. I have figured out that the problem was with my deployment script (capistrano). So I simply started from the basics and let bundle/capistrano do all the work.

Comment: Thanks, but can I get a +1 for the help? ;-) And _yes_ reading the guide saves you pain from a few gotchas.

Comment: TBH, install guides in general starts off as "hey this is so easy, you can do this with your eyes closed" then you run into so much issues because effectively you have been installing with your eyes closed. If I ever write an app ... going to be straight from the begining ... this bleeding hard so get a coffee, lock the door and and do this ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the answer ... which is in the error itself!

head over to the refinery blog git and locate that missing file:
[Git Hub Refinery Blog/comment_mailer.rb](https://raw.github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog/master/app/mailers/blog/comment_mailer.rb)

Download that to: app/mailers/refinery/blog

And presto, no more issues with passenger (not sure why the error popped up in the first place if the refinery blog has it within their app!?!)

Comment: Its actually on: https://raw.github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog/master/app/mailers/refinery/blog/comment_mailer.rb